Get a list of all context menu items added by third-party applications
I need to get a list of all context menu items added by third-party applications under Windows.
For example, when I install Notepad++, it adds "Edit with Notepad++" in the context menu of files.
I tried to search "Edit with Notepad++" string in Windows registry but found nothing.
In general, I need a C++ program that will collect all third-party context menu items for specified file/folder together with their handlers

Is this for an application or a one-time type deal? Nirsoft have tools that can view and export the data. As for finding the string, it probably uses string redirection so the value is just a dll file with a index value.

@NickSlash this is for application, not one-time

This isn't straightforward as menu items are often added dynamically (e.g. via code), and the available menu items may change depending on what objects are selected.

Context menus are constructed on demand based on the object. A folder will have entries different from a PDF document, for example. It's a rather unusual requirement to want to list all possible entries. What's the specific use case for this?

@IInspectable You are right. I am already edited my question. I need all third-party context menu items for specified file/folder

You can call IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf(IID_IContextMenu) and call QueryContextMenu to ask it to fill in the menu items. Then you can look at what got added to the menu.

@RaymondChen Yes, it returns menu in IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu, but I don`t know how can I extract from IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu only third-party menu items. I tried all possible uFlags values but there is no flag to get only third-party menu items

There is no distinction between first party, second party, or third party providers. Not even Windows knows which is which. The first party providers use the same registration mechanism as the third party providers. (For example .msi files register under HKCR.msi -> HKCR\Msi.Package, the same way a third party provider would register their file extension. And then there are the mixed cases, where .gitattributes is registered by a third party program [Git for Windows], but launches a first party program [Notepad].)

@JoeJ This sounds like a possible XY Problem. What is the actual goal you are trying to accomplish, and why do you think finding the 3rd party items/handlers is the solution?

@RaymondChen In some cases, the registry does not contain direct entries for the context menu. Instead, the context menu is added via a DLL. For example, I found an entry for Notepad++ in the registry: HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ANotepad++64 and the Default value specifies CLSID {B298D29A-A6ED-11DE-BA8C-A68E55D89593}. In the registry, this CLSID corresponds to the entry HKCR\CLSID{B298D29A-A6ED-11DE-BA8C-A68E55D89593}\InprocServer32, which points to path\to\NppShell_06.dll Is it possible to access the context menu via CLSID/DLL? Read its text and execute it. If yes, then how?

@RemyLebeau i am trying to implement function like IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu   . Generally I want to display context menu of the file but with some customization.

Trying to replicate the context menu registration mechanism is a fool's  errand. New registration mechanisms show up over time (AQS, DelegateExecute, AppxManifest.xml) and you'll be constantly trying to catch up. Why not just call IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu to get the default context menu, and then customize the result?

@RaymondChen Thanks for the tip. I don't know how to customize the result of IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu. For example, I want to remove the menu item "Delete", "Send to" and "Give access to" from the menu returned by IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu for .txt file. I don't know how to identify these menu items to remove them. Can you suggest how to remove these menu items? The first idea is to check the menu text, but the menu text depends on the OS language and can be variable. I have no idea.

Use GetCommandString to get the canonical names that are not translated.

I suggest you could refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-implement-the-icontextmenu-interface

@RaymondChen 1) language-independent command name is not available for all menu items, for example, it is missing for "Give access to" menu item. 2) Also, through IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu, it is not possible to access the context menu that appears when requesting a context menu by right clicking on the background inside a folder. Considering all of this, IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu is not suitable in this case and I think I need to deal with the registry. Correct me if I'm wrong. If I'm right, then I'd like to return to the previous question: how can I request a context menu from DLL?

IShellFolder::CreateViewObject gives you the background menu.

@Anders unfortunately, it`s buggy. For example, "new" menu does not show correct submenus: https://i.ibb.co/2F0B8s3/buggy-new.png also it returns empty submenu for "Give access to" https://i.ibb.co/JBSSdqb/empty-give-access-to.png

You have to call HandleMenuMsg (or preferably HandleMenuMsg2) in order for owner-draw menus and on-demand submenus to work..

"How can I request a context menu from DLL?" I guess you could do what COM does. GetProcAddress for DllGetClassObject, ask it for the class object of the context menu extension, then QI for IShellExtInit and give it a data object for the item. Then QI for IContextMenu and call its QueryContextMenu. Not sure why you want to do it the hard way. This will however miss out on other context menu registration mechanisms like static registry (with AQS filtering), AppxManifest.xml, and DelegateExecute/IExecuteCommand.

If HandleMenuMsg2 is not supported, then use HandleMenuMsg.

@RaymondChen Thank you Mr. Raymond! After calling HandleMenuMsg2 in WM_INITMENUPOPUP handler, it shows correct submenus for GetUIObjectOf, but for CreateViewObject problem still exists

You may want to study this series on hosting context menus https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823

You have to call HandleMenuMsg(2) for every message while the menu is visible.

@RaymondChen Nothing was changed when I start calling HandleMenuMsg2 for every message. Submenus still invisible on CreateViewObject

It seems that the problem you are having is unrelated to the question.
